# Invoke the back-to-app button programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

Is is possible to call the "back-to-app" button programmatically? I have only seen questions for the scenraio when people want to call back-to-app from `OtherApp` which I understand why it shouldn't be available.

`MyApp -> OtherApp` : call back-to-app from OtherApp.

However in my scenario is this:

`OtherApp -> MyApp` : call back-to-app from MyApp.

Is it possible to send the user from `MyApp` back to where they were before? Because my app has completed its purpose?

Comment: I'm not aware of any standard APIs to accomplish this with arbitrary combinations of apps, but some specific apps allow you to accomplish this via custom URL schemes, X-Callback-URL, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. It looks like you're in app A, then opening app B using some URL scheme. When you're done in app B, just use a URL scheme for app A to open that one again.

Comment: Returning to the calling app via a URL scheme will open it in a new context, whereas the back button will return to the state as it was when the second app was opened.  E.g., calling from a safari www page and then returning to that page.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re talking about the button that appears at the top left when switching apps, no you can not invoke that button.

For your app to open another app you’ll need to know the URL Scheme of the app you want to open. The other app must also be setup to handle this URL Scheme.

If you own both apps you can implement the URL Scheme yourself. If not, you’ll need to reach out to the developer of the other app to see if they have a URL Scheme you can open their app with.

Apple docs: [Defining a Custom URL Scheme for Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app)

Comment: Yes I have url schemes implemented. However I want it the other way around so that the other app opens my url scheme, I handle it in my app and then send the user back to the app it was opened from.

Comment: Unless you also own the other app, there’s no way to have them open your app.

Comment: I do own it. It does open my app but then I want to close my app and go back to the previous one. So I was wondering if there is another way than implementing another url scheme for the previous app too

Comment: Please update your question with these details. You can use the URL Scheme you already have implemented and pass parameters for any special use cases. See the documentation I've linked to for details.

Comment: What's the problem with implementing a url scheme for the first app?

Comment: There is no problem, but I want to use this app as a debug accessory to all my other apps and would have to implement url schemes in each and every one of the apps. So as I see, there is no way the button can be invoked. Thank you for your kind replies! :)